# Is there an elegant way to float a block into the block that is from the left of it

Tags: html, css

The description is a bit confusing, but I don't see a way how to explain it better.

Schematically it looks like

[image]

and the layout is defined as

```
<div id="outer_a">
    <div id="a1"></div>
    <div id="a2"></div>
</div>

<div id="outer_b">
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D3Ftp/

I need a solution that would help a cyan block to go right after a yellow one so that it looked like

[image]

As a result.

Limitations: the layout cannot be changed. Well, minor changes are allowed but there should be - 2 blocks wrapped by a div on the left and another block wrapped in a div in the right.

My solution is terrible - `margin-left: -52px;`.

Not mention it is terrible by itself but the thing is that the left block may not exist, in this case the blue one should act as it would with a normal flow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just put the DIV you want to move inside the other DIV?

Comment: @Lightning Dust: they are 2 different independent widgets and rendered to a page separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your solution is terrible considering your limitations. I would simply do:

```
#outer_a + #outer_b {
    margin-left: -52px;        
}
```

In this case the whole `#outer_b` is going to be placed according to the normal flow when `#outer_a` does not exist or will be put inside (visually) of `#outer_a` otherwise

Answer (score 2):

I've made an update to your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/D3Ftp/1/

Here's the updated CSS:

```
#b {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: cyan;
   position: relative;
}   

#outer_a ~ #outer_b #b {
    left:-100%;
}
```

The `left` style will only be applied, if `#outer_a` is followed by `#outer_b`. Try and remove the first `div` block in the fiddle, and see the magic :)

Edit:
I see, that where I've been using percentages, the width of `#outer_b` does not change as per your requirements. I don't think there's a prettier solution than the `marign-left:-Ypx;` for that specific requirement.

Comment: "the width of #outer_b does not change as per your requirements" -- actually at the moment it's not required for `#outer_b` to collapse, so your solution fits perfectly

Comment: well that's great to hear :) If the requirements ever change, you'll know where to modify the CSS

Comment: Yep, upvoting both of you but I see the other solution as less evil :-) PS: personally I've found and will use another solution, but it's very project-specific and isn't html/css tricky